# GXT Textfield postfix

Tags: gwt, extjs, gxt

I try to build a simple form.

Calc:    [***_*___**] bar

So the Textfield with the prefix is no problem. But the postfix "bar". Currenty I have no idea to fix this problem. Here ist the current code:

```
TextField<String> field = new TextField<String>();      
field.setFieldLabel("Calc");
field.setAllowBlank(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The FormPanel renders all Fields in a LABEL: INPUTFIELD way.
To render other widgets within a FormPanel I would use the AdpaterField that contains the real TextField and the postfix.

```
    HorizontalPanel container = new HorizontalPanel();
    AdapterField field = new AdapterField(container);
    field.setFieldLabel("Calc");
    TextField<String> inputField = new TextField<String>();
    inputField.setAllowBlank(false);
    container.add(inputField);
    container.add(new Html("bar"));
```